# Internet explorer 11 shuts down after download of file

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

I try to download a file. For that I'm clicking on a link which opens a new pop-up. In this popup the file will be downloaded.

Normally, on all other computers, **only** the pop-up just closes after the download and in my "main" browser-window stays open and the file is shown with the possibility to "open" or "save". 
But in my case the popup and the main window both close right after the download.

The strange part: If I press F12 and have the developer-console open, then the main-browser stays open.

I've already removed all cookies and temporary data. 
Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: Is it happening for any downloads? Is there entries in the event log about IE crash?

Comment: In which event log do you mean? In the console? no, there aren't any errors

Comment: I mean `Windows Event Viewer - Windows Logs - Application`. It could be found in `Administrative Tools`